# How can I trigger focusout on all fields in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a method to trigger focusout every time a user tabs to the next field in a form. I know that I can't use a class element as it will bind to every field with that class but I want to avoid this:

```
$("#element1").focusout( function() {
        //do something
});
$("#element2").focusout( function() {
        //do something else
});
$("#element3").focusout( function() {
        //do something different
});
```

Is there a simple way to check a field only after a .focusin for that field or am I looking for the wrong solution?

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
     $("input, textarea").focusout( function() {
             //do something different
     });
```